# Mysql slow query log Errcode: 13 - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, permission-denied, mysql-slow-query-log

I want to enable slow query log.
When I execute the following query

`set global slow_query_log = 'ON';`

I get :

```
#29 - File '/var/log/mysqld_slow.log' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

I tried solution here :
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98340 but I have issue on last command :

```
touch /var/log/mysqld_slow.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld_slow.log (also tried mysql:adm)
chmod 640 /var/log/mysqld_slow.log (also tried 666)
chcon -t mysqld_log_t /var/log/mysqld_slow.log
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/var/log/mysqld_slow.log'
```

Comment: Sounds like apparmor is blocking you. If you try to make a service create a file in an unauthorized location, the security service will block that. Read https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/8.0/security/apparmor.html and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand why, but changing the path to /var/log/mysql/mysqld_slow.log is working.

Certainly due to parent folder permissions ?

Can't have a solution to put file in /var/log/mysqld_slow.log ?
I'm using ubuntu

Comment: It is indeed parent folder permissions, must `chown` to the `mysql` user

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i just remove the file

```
rm -rf mysqld_slow.log
```

and then restart mysql

```
systemctl restart mysql
```

it regenerate the file, it works

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file in MySQL variables to some new name, I have just renamed the file from a variable and it is working properly. And MySQL automatically created the file for me in the path.
The defautl path is: /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log - rename the file to slow_query_log or something else

Hope it may work for you.